# How to access a variable with random value inside a class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
   class Session{
        protected $git =  md5(rand(1,6)); 
        public function __construct($config = array())
        {
           //// some code
            $ses_id = $this->git;

        }
        public function _start_session()
        {
           //code again..
        }
      }
```

Here I can't assign a random value like this to variable called git. How can I do this if it is possible? 
That random value need to be first time generated value only till the time it converts to Null.

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue bit more?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: You cannot write expression(assign value calling by function) to set value of variable outside function of a class.So you need to do that inside function of this class.Constructor is best choice here.

Comment: here the issue is ..for every time constructor is called the value of git will change...but i need the first time generated value only every time..how can i do this.

Answer (score 4):

Perform random inside your constructor,

```
class Session{
        protected $git; 
        public function __construct($config = array())
        {
           //// some code
           $this->git =  md5(rand(1,6));
           $ses_id = $this->git;

        }
        public function _start_session()
        {
           //code again..
        }
      }
```

Comment: here the issue is ..for every time constructor is called the value of git will change...but i need the first time generated value only every time..how can i do this.

Comment: to solve this, dont call session class multiple times, just reuse it. When your calling the constructor, your instantiating the class and creating a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable inside a class,initialize the variables in class inside a constructor, which sets the variables once the object for that class is declared anywhere in the code.

I updated this answer if you want to do not change your session variable on each constructor call then use the below procedure.

```
class Session{
       protected $git;
        public function __construct($config = array())
        {
           $this->git  =  md5(rand(1,6)); 
           if(!isset($_SESSION['ses_id']))
            {
            $_SESSION['ses_id'] = $this->git;
            }
        }
        public function _start_session()
        {
           //code again..
        }
      }
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: You declare it in the class and instantiate it in the constructor.

Comment: here the issue is ..for every time constructor is called the value of git will change...but i need the first time generated value only every time..how can i do this.

Comment: @JohnSk, i have updated my answer please check that, now you will be able to have a constant random variable in the session that was generated on the first call of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of your variable in your constructor.

constructor will run every time you create an instance of your class.

try this code:

```
      class Session{
        protected $git;
        public function __construct($config = array())
        {
           //// some code
           $this->git = md5(rand(1,6));
        }
        public function _start_session()
        {
           //code again..
        }
      }
```

:)

Comment: here the issue is ..for every time constructor is called the value of git will change...but i need the first time generated value only every time..how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a global variable to track the random number:

```
class Session{
    protected $git;
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        //// some code
        if (!isset($GLOBALS['random_val'])) {
            $GLOBALS['random_val'] = md5(rand(1,6));
        }

        $this->git = $GLOBALS['random_val'];
        $ses_id = $this->git;
        var_dump("Session ID: ".$ses_id);

    }

    public function _start_session()
    {
        //code again..
    }
}


$ses1 = new Session(); // Outputs string(44) "Session ID: 1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc"
$ses2 = new Session(); // Outputs string(44) "Session ID: 1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc"
```